# Android pass context causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, class, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-context

I am trying to make methods work from other classes than the current activity. In this case there is a backup mechanism which sometimes uses toasts and works flawlessly if the method is in the same class as the activity but every time it's called there is a NullPointerException.

These are the essential lines from the main activity:

```
Backup bckp;
private Context context = Main.this;
bckp.copyBackup(backupdir, backupdirfile, database, context);
```

and the called method:

```
public void copyBackup(final String backupdir,
        final String target, final String source, final Context context) {
    final File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (sdcard.canWrite()) {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(source);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error finding the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File dir = new File (backupdir);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(target);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error creating the backup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try {
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error copying the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error ending the copy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No SD card found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It makes no sense to me why it works if all is in one class but not if it's in a separate class...
Thanks for your help!

Edit:

```
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at maturaarbeit.nicola_pfister.marks.Main$9$1.onClick(Main.java:271)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-08 14:13:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and highlight the line where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: What is at line 271 of `Main`?

Comment: @Egor I added the stacktrace but I don't know how to highlight lines. It's thrown in the Main.class on "bckp.copyBackup(backupdir, backupdirfile, database, context);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized `bckp` so it is `null` when you try to call a function on it. Your `context` is fine

```
Backup bckp;
```

Make it

```
Backup bckp = new Backup();  // send parameters if your constructor takes them
private Context context = Main.this;
bckp.copyBackup(backupdir, backupdirfile, database, context);
```

Comment: Oooh... of course... I even had an example for that in the very same code but was irritated by Eclipse asking for a constructor in the initialized class. Anyway it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are most welcome. By the way, the first line after the exception in your logcat which references your code is the place to start. That's how I knew it was in there and to look for an object that had a function being performed on it